# Fatal error: Class entry requested for an object without PHP class

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Class entry requested for an object without PHP class
```

when running the code below in 70% of tries with Xdebug active:

```
if (isset($billingData['email'])) {
    $this->email = $billingData['email'];
}
```

The line where it fails actually depends on the line where the breakpoint is set.

I tend to connect that issue with 5.4.x (I have PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.1 with Xdebug v2.2.3), because the error doesn't occur on 5.3.x. When Xdebug is active, NetBeans throws

```
Socket Exception occured
If you have any Watches, try to remove them and restart debugger. If removing Watches doesn't help or you don't have any Watches, please file an issue and provide the exact steps to reproduce your problem. Please attach the IDE log. Attaching your project would also be very helpful.
```

When not debugging, the script just silently fails with "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error in Chrome.

Comment: This is PECL issue I think.

Comment: should probably go to http://xdebug.org/support.php